# Where to start with Data Science

Tags: machine-learning, r, data-mining

I know next to nothing about Data Science. Where should I start? Where do you recommend I should take courses (hopefully free)? Or even a book.

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning

Comment: Why do you want to learn about data science? As a hobby or just to see what all the fuss is about, free courses are fine. Professionally (and especially depending on background), consider university courses.

Comment: @Hobbes I have a computer science degree. I want to get into data science and start building my career

Comment: Also take a course in statistics in addition to the ML courses, then; they are complementary.

Comment: Cool, I think you're in a good place. Learning ML + Stats online and making a portfolio will help you become competitive.

Comment: 80% of data science activity is preprocessing data. So work daily with text-data specific command-line tools.  Book: http://datascienceatthecommandline.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I started studying in [Datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com) and I really recommend this [Machine learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) course it's very complete for new learners.

Udacity has this [Deep-learning](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud730) course and it's a complement for the Coursera [Machine learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) course.

It's very important to research a lot in other sources but there you can paint a path for your **Data Science** skills through these ones.

I'm working and studying in Machine learning and I store the test projects in [this repository](https://github.com/haroldjcastillo/ml-test), but is very important to have a little bit of knowledge of [python](https://www.python.org/) and [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)

*Already exist other languages and tools like [R](https://www.r-project.org/) for test your data sets*